# What is the AWS Lambda dependency for Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, aws-lambda

I want to use [AWSLambdaClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html) java class in my Android Studio project for invoking lambda functions. What is the dependency that should be added in the gradle file dependencies section? For some reason I can't seem to find it online.

I did manage to find the dependency for the AWSMobileClient class which I needed as well, which is `'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.16.+@aar'`. But the dependency for AWSLambdaClient couldn't be found. AI suggested `'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-client:2.17.1'` but it didn't work.

Comment: I assume you mean `AWSLambdaClient`, which you linked to, instead of `AWSClient` which you mention several times in your question, but doesn't seem to be a class that actually exists.

Comment: Also, if you are hitting a REST API that just so happens to have a Lambda function as the backend, you should be using a REST API client. The `AWSLambdaClient` would be used to invoke a Lambda function directly, not for calling a REST API. The REST API abstracts away the backend implementation from the front-end client (your Android app) so that the client doesn't need some implementation specific AWS Lambda client library.

Comment: It would be better if you build your REST API with API gateway backed by AWS Lambda. to invoke the REST API you can use any HTTP client library

Comment: @MarkB Sorry and thanks for the clarification. I need to invoke a Lambda function directly. I have a prewritten code that does so but the imports regarding AWSLambdaClient and some other classes from the same package are missing their corresponding dependency. Couldn't find it.

Comment: @VikramS Thanks, I would rather use these libraries if possible since I am putting together a prewritten code

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html) says this would be the Gradle dependencies needed to include the AWS Lambda portion of the AWS Java SDK in a Gradle project:

```
dependencies {    
    implementation(platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.21.1"))
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:lambda")
}
```

I'm not sure that's going to work in the Android runtime though.

---

Note that this is also likely to inflate the size of your Android project quite a bit. It is a much cleaner solution to expose your services via AWS API Gateway, and use a standard HTTP client in your Android app to call that API.